# javascript If Less than, display selling out

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to set up a script to display "sold out" label if the item has 0 and if the item has 1000 to display "selling out" and this works fine.

I want to know how can i set up the label to display "selling out" if the item is **less** than 1000 so not exactly 1000

I kind of just winged it with this one by putting a "<" in front of the number 1000.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jq(function() { 
    jq("span.spn_U3").each(function() { 
        switch(jq(this).text()) { 
            case "0": 
                jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
                    .append('<div class="styleoverlay soldout"><span>Sold Out</span></div>'); 
                break; 
            case "<1000": 
                jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
                    .append('<div class="styleoverlay sellingout"><span>Selling Out</span></div>'); 
                break;  
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: also, please format your JS so it's readable. Makes it more likely to get people to provide answers.

Comment: @Anonymous clearly stated in the title and second paragraph.

Just to clarify, wanting to display "Selling out" from 1-999 value and display "sold out" on 0 value

Comment: @DrydenLong wouldn't that only apply to values that are 999 to be exact and not from 1-999?

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that... I've got something for you though, stay tuned. **EDIT** Nevermind - meager beat me to it, use his answer

Comment: @user3303786 Actually you simply stated facts.  You never said that there was a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a `switch` statement. Use an `if/else`:

```
qty = parseInt(jq(this).text(), 10);

if (qty == 0) {
  jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
    .append('<div class="styleoverlay soldout"><span>Sold Out</span></div>');  
} else if (qty < 1000) {
  jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
    .append('<div class="styleoverlay sellingout"><span>Selling Out</span></div>'); 
}
```

Note that you *can* use a `switch` statement with complex cases, but there is no compelling reason to do so for such a simple set of cases:

```
qty = 0;

switch(true) {
case qty == 0:
  jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
    .append('<div class="styleoverlay soldout"><span>Sold Out</span></div>');  
  break;
case qty < 1000:
  jq(this).closest(".stylesummarytext").prev()
    .append('<div class="styleoverlay sellingout"><span>Selling Out</span></div>'); 
  break;
}
```

Comment: And just to clarify for OP as to why: The original code is using strings of text rather than integers, meaning the `<` symbol will not behave as expected. No math was being done in the `switch` statement, but with the `if/else` statement in this answer, you can successfully apply your rule to all integers below 1000.

Comment: Thanks for this @DrydenLong just a quick question

what is the number '10' in the first part of the code stating?

qty = parseInt(jq(this).text(), 10);

sorry i've still fairly new to jq/js

Comment: @user3303786 That is the `radix` and it specifies the numbering system to be used. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Javascript switch..case certainly does not handle boolean operators embedded inside strings.
Just use standard if conditionals.